# Hpple XPath query issue on IOS

Tags: ios, xpath, html-parsing, hpple

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
   <divv id="items">
        <trr>
            <td>
                <p>Cars</p>
                <a>Toyota</a>
                <a>Opel</a>
                <a>Audi</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Planes</p>
                <a>A320</a>
                <a>B787</a>
                <a>B767</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <div/>
```

What I want is to create a XPath query so I can retrieve only the Cars.
Currently I am using this: `//div[@id='items']/tr/td`. But with this I get also the Plane items. I do not know how to test for the 'p' tag.

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that you can, since the cars *are not contained within the `p` element* unless you just take the first group (and assume that they are the cars).

Comment: What is the syntax for taking the first group ? I am not really good at this xpath queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If picking the first group is enough, then you can use:

```
//div[@id='items']/tr/td[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//div[@id='items']/tr/td[p='Cars']
```

The last predicate tests the existence of a `<p>` child element with `Cars` text content and thus filters out the `<td>` with `<p>Planes</p>`.